# How can I use vectorize or array broadcasting to get rid of this for-loop?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

Is there a way to use np.vectorize or numpy array broadcasting to get rid of this for-loop?

```
xs = np.random.uniform(-2,2,size=(3,2))

Qs = np.array([
    [
        [4,2],
        [2,2]
    ],
    [
        [1,1],
        [1,1]
    ],
    [
        [2,2],
        [2,2]
    ]
])
rs = np.array([
    [1,-1],
    [1,1],
    [-1,1]
])

g = lambda Q, r, x: 0.5*x.T @ Q @ x + r @ x

# loop over all of the elements of Qs, rs, and xs 
# evaluating g at each point
results = []
for Q, r, x in zip(Qs, rs, xs):
    results.append(g(Q, r, x))
print(np.array(results))
```

I've tried just using array-broadcasting:

```
results = g(Qs, rs, xs)
```

but it states

```
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 2 is different from 3)
```

and I have tried vectorizing the funciton:

```
g_vec = np.vectorize(g)
results = g_vec(Qs, rs, xs)
print(results)
```

but it gives this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'numpy.float64' and 'numpy.int32'
```

and doesn't seem to loop over each Q, r and x np.array

Comment: If using `lambda` is not required, this can be a bit faster: `results = (0.5 * xs[:,None] @ Qs @ xs[:,:,None] + rs[:,None] @ xs[:,:,None])[:,0,0]`.
`None`s are used to create new axes (to ensure correct dimensions when multiplying matrices).

Comment: `@/matmul` can handle 'batches' if that dimension is first of 3. You have (3,2) and (3,2,2) arrays. Expanding the smaller to (3,1,2) and (3,2,1) takes advantage of this.  `np.einsum` could be used instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a signature to your vectorization function to properly multiply the matrices:

```py
g_vec = np.vectorize(g, signature='(n,n),(n),(n)->()')
results = g_vec(Qs, rs, xs)
print(results)
```

[More on signatures.](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

Comment: `vectorize` is relatively slow, and the use of signature even slower.